# Can I define default values for attributes in ember components when using angle-brackets syntax (1.13)?

Tags: ember.js

I'm testing ember-1.13.0-beta.1 on on an application and can't find a way to provide default values for attributes. I was previously using properties with default values:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  myAttribute: 'default-value',
});

{{my-component myAttribute=otherValue}}
```

I tried this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  attrs:{
    myAttribute: 'default-value',
  },
});

<my-component myAttribute={{otherValue}} />
```

but it doesn't work.
Did I miss something?

Comment: For those reading that question: angle-brackets syntax is disabled by default in 1.13.0-beta.2 . Ember.js team produced new [RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/angle-bracket-components/active/0000-component-unification.md) for this syntax. For now, I use didReceiveAttrs() to mix default values with attrs provided ones. Not sure it's a good way to do it though.